# How can i check if record exists in database before insert using maatwebsite/excel package version 3.1

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I have an application developed in Laravel which requires to import data from excel file into the database table,I have been using maatwebsite/excel 2.1, i upgraded to 3.1. I have gone through the documentation and found something like `Excel::import(new ExcelImport, request()->file('fileToUpload'));`, where by ExcelImport is the class which will save the all data of the excel file into the database, but with this approach how can check if the record in the excel file exists in the database before inserting?

I really need help and will appreciate any insight on how to achieve it as I am stack and all the articles seems the same

Thanks in advance and

Comment: Please have a look at their validation docs 
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html

Comment: you can use `createOrUpdate` method for this in your import class.

Comment: ```public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {

        for ($row = 1; $row < sizeof($collection); $row++){


            $entityName = $collection[$row][0];
            $regno = $collection[$row][1] ?? 1000;
            $check = ObrsBlsPayment::where(['obrsEntityName'=>$entityName])->first();
            if (!empty($check)){
                ObrsBlsPayment::where(['id'=>$check->id])->update(array(
                    'obrsRegno'=>$regno
                ));
            }

        }```

Comment: I am converting all the excel data to a collection, Does the update not working with collection?